# How to make MySQL aware of multi-byte characters in LIKE and REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a MySQL table with two columns, both utf8_unicode_ci collated. It contains the following rows. Except for ASCII, the second field also contains Unicode codepoints like U+02C8 (MODIFIED LETTER VERTICAL LINE) and U+02D0 (MODIFIED LETTER TRIANGULAR COLON).

```
 word   | ipa
--------+----------
 Hallo  | haˈloː
 IPA    | ˌiːpeːˈʔaː
```

I need to search the second field with LIKE and REGEXP, but MySQL (5.0.77) seems to interpret these fields as bytes, not as characters.

```
SELECT * FROM pronunciation WHERE ipa LIKE '%ha?lo%';  -- 0 rows
SELECT * FROM pronunciation WHERE ipa LIKE '%ha??lo%'; -- 1 row

SELECT * FROM pronunciation WHERE ipa REGEXP 'ha.lo';  -- 0 rows
SELECT * FROM pronunciation WHERE ipa REGEXP 'ha..lo'; -- 1 row
```

I'm quite sure that the data is stored correctly, as it seems good when I retrieve it and shows up fine in phpMyAdmin. I'm on a shared host, so I can't really install programs.

How can I solve this problem? If it's not possible: is there a plausible work-around that does not involve processing the entire database with PHP every time? There are 40 000 lines, and I'm not dead-set on using MySQL (or UTF8, for that matter). I only have access to PHP and MySQL on the host.

**Edit:** There is an open 4-year-old MySQL bug report,  [Bug #30241 Regular expression problems](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30241), which notes that the regexp engine works  byte-wise. Thus, I'm looking for a work-around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDITED to incorporate fix to valid critisism**

Use the `HEX()` function to render your bytes to hexadecimal and *then* use `RLIKE` on that, for example:

```
select * from mytable
where hex(ipa) rlike concat('(..)*', hex('needle'), '(..)*'); -- looking for 'needle' in haystack, but maintaining hex-pair alignment.
```

The odd unicode chars render consistently to their hex values, so you're searching over standard 0-9A-F chars.

This works for "normal" columns too, you just don't need it.

p.s. @Kieren's (valid) point addressed using `rlike` to enforce char pairs

Comment: I don't think this will work. The two bytes `BA`,`AB` would be rendered as `BAAB`, which would then match a search for the byte `AA`, which isn't in the source.  Assuming `hex()` renders without spaces or delimiters.

Comment: Interesting idea. Might get it to work with regexes by first making sure that all chars are the same length (e.g. UTF32), then `hex()` and replacing `.` wildcards with `.{8}`. There would still be a lot of work-arounds for getting all the regex features to work right, though.

Comment: Kieren's point has been addressed in the current version of the answer - regex is used to keep the comparison aligned with hex digit pairs.

Comment: Thanks @Tim! My first bounty :D

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks for the answer :) This inspired the current solution.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not dead-set on using MySQL

Postgres seems to handle it quite fine:

```
test=# select 'ˌˈʔ' like '___';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

test=# select 'ˌˈʔ' ~ '^.{3}$';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

If you go down that road, note that in Postgres' `ilike` operator matches that of MySQL's `like`. (In Postgres, `like` is case-sensitive.)

---

For the MySQL-specific solution, you mind be able to work around by binding some [user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html) (maybe bind the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/)?) into MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I meant with "I only have access to PHP and MySQL" is that there are no other languages or database systems available to me. On the other hand, I would be fine with a PHP-only solution.

Comment: Sure. If you've even the remotest possibility of switching hosts and using one with Postgres, do consider it though. You'll also get the ability to index the IPAs using the [full text engine](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html). It would take a special dictionary, but you'd then be able to index-scan your data using text search queries instead of seq scanning it using `like` statements.

Comment: I've added a reference to user-defined functions for MySQL.

Comment: Re: Postgres: Sounds very useful. That will work if no other viable solution is found.

Comment: Re Postgres, you might also find the [trigram search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) and the [clustering aggregate](http://pgxn.org/dist/kmeans/doc/kmeans.html) functionality interesting. :-)

Answer (score -2):

You have problems with UTF8? Eliminate them.

How many special characters do you use? Are you using only locase letters, am I right? So, my tip is: Write a function, which converts spec chars to regular chars, e.g. "æ" ->"A" and so on, and add a column to the table which stores that converted value (you have to convert all values first, and upon each insert/update). When searching, you just have to convert search string with the same function, and use it on that field with regexp.

If there're too many kind of special chars, you should convert it to multi-char. 1. Avoid finding "aa" in the "ba ab" sequence use some prefix, like "@ba@ab". 2. Avoid finding "@a" in "@ab" use fixed length tokens, say, 2.