# MySQL REPLACE affects 0 rows but WHERE ... LIKE returns 90

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For some reason while using PhpMyAdmin returns 90 rows when running:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM le_wp_posts 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%'
```

But the following updates 3 rows only:

```
UPDATE le_wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â', '') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%'
```

I have also tried it omitting the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement. Is there any obvious reason I'm overlooking that's causing this issue? Or what steps can I take further to investigate the cause? My SQL is not the best.

Comment: Did you try using the select clause in the where condition :
`WHERE post_content IN (SELECT distinct post_content FROM le_wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%')`

Comment: @pat `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'le_wp_posts' for update in FROM clause ` is the result of `UPDATE le_wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â', '') WHERE post_content IN (SELECT distinct post_content FROM le_wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause - check this out

Comment: Dirty solution :
UPDATE le_wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â', '') WHERE post_content IN (SELECT distinct post_content FROM (select * from le_wp_posts) as x WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%')

Comment: @Pat thanks, was looking at that as you posted. Returned 0 rows updated. I've even changed the connector charset to correlate to the server charset. I'm going to try a regex replacement

Comment: Just to be sure: have you checked that there are no triggers blocking your update on that table?

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482531/how-to-make-mysql-aware-of-multi-byte-characters-in-like-and-regexp

Comment: @Jens ni triggers. @walen - so I tried `SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM le_wp_posts 
where hex(post_content) rlike concat('(..)*', hex('Â'), '(..)*')` and got 0 rows, while my original select gets 90

Comment: Shall I dump the DB so someone can test?

Comment: What is your charset? If you use e.g. `latin1`, `select * from le_wp_posts where post_content LIKE '%Â%'` will search for (and return) `A` and `a` too. Check your results if they actually use an `Â`. When you update the rows, you will get the number of actually changed rows. This is the expected behaviour. You can force a collation if you want.

Comment: Your `COUNT` query searches case-insensitive, as `LIKE` is (usually) case-insensitive. But pay attention to `REPLACE` being [case-sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) regarding the first parameter. So you might have some lower-case chars in there. You could dump the records that are returned by your first query and cross-check.

Comment: What does the following query return `select post_content from le_wp_posts where replace(post_content, 'Â', '') like '%Â%'` ?

Answer (score 3):

I did the following test...

1) Create a table with some data:

```
create table test(col varchar(10));

insert into test values ('abc'), ('dbe');
```

2) Select number of rows using your same filter (but different character):

```
select count(*)
from test
where col like '%B%' -- note the uppercase
;
```

Got the following result:

```
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                
| count(*) |                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                
|        2 |                                                                                                                                                                
+----------+ 

1 row in set
```

3) Tried your update:

```
update test 
set col = replace(col, 'B', '') -- note the uppercase
where col like '%B%' -- note the uppercase
;
```

And got this result:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)                                                                                                                                        
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

In my case, a default character set and collation where used on table creation. The default character set was 'latin1' and collation 'latin1_swedish_ci'. Note the `ci` at the end of the collation.... it means **case insensitive**. So, the `LIKE` filter did a case insensitive search, found 2 rows, but the `REPLACE` function, as can be seen on documentation, is **case sensitive**. Probably, as in my case, the update found the same number of rows as in the select, but updated less data because of the case restriction on `REPLACE`.

If this is your problem, can't you just run two updates, one for the uppercase case and one for the lowercase? I'll try to develop a solution on one update...

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) about the `REPLACE(str, from_str, to_str)` function:

> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str replaced by the string to_str. **REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive** match when searching for from_str.

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) about the `LIKE` operator:

> The following two statements illustrate that **string comparisons are not case sensitive** unless one of the operands is a case sensitive (uses a case-sensitive collation or is a binary string):

The first example:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
        -> 1
```

The second example:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE _latin1 'ABC' COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
        -> 0
```

Note the `cs` at the end of the collation. It means **case sensitive**.

Comment: "If this is your problem, can't you just run two updates, one for the uppercase case and one for the lowercase?" Probably will work for the one character but what about Title Case for long strings?

Answer (score 3):

If you take a utf8-encoded `£` (`C2A3`, treated as utf8) and store it into a latin1 column, when you read it back, you get `Â£` (`C2A3`, treated as latin1).  Removing the `Â` will work for about 32 characters, but will fail for many other characters.  *And it will make the table harder to repair!*

Let's look at an example of what you tried to store, together with the `HEX` of that ended up in the table.  Also, let's look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to confirm my suspicion that the target it `latin1`.

[*This*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831) discusses the `HEX` debugging technique.  And it discusses "Best Practice", which includes declaring, during the connection, that you really have utf8, not latin1.  And it talks about "Mojibake", with an example of where `ñ` turns into `Ã±`, making `REPLACE` a messy prospect.

Your symptom with `LIKE` is consistent with character set mismatches.

Answer (score 2):

The LIKE is Case-insensitive but Replace is Case-sensitive, to bypass that use the following query:

```
UPDATE le_wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(LOWER(post_content), LOWER('Â'), '') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%'
```

OR if you want the final result not to be lower case:

```
UPDATE le_wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(REPLACE(post_content, LOWER('Â'), ''), 'Â', '') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%'
```

Comment: Case insensitivity depends on the collation of the column.

Comment: `LIKE` is either case-sensitive or case-insensitive, depending on the collation.  (I'm quibbling with your first sentence.)  In my answer, I don't see `LIKE` as having any relevance to the _real problem and solution_.

Answer (score 1):

```
--you just need to put N before string pattern too (if you want look for unicode char)*/
Update le_wp_posts
Set post_content=REPLACE(post_content,N'Â','')
where post_content like '%Â%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using JOIN as below:

```
UPDATE le_wp_posts l
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.post_content  
            FROM le_wp_posts t 
            WHERE t.post_content LIKE '%Â%') t ON l.post_content = t.post_content
SET l.post_content = REPLACE(l.post_content, 'Â', '')
```

Comment: Ok there was an error in the query as `a` isn't a table, so I change `a.post_content` to `l.post_content`  like so: `UPDATE le_wp_posts l INNER JOIN (SELECT t.post_content FROM le_wp_posts t WHERE t.post_content LIKE '%Â%') t ON l.post_content = t.post_content SET l.post_content = REPLACE(t.post_content, 'Â', '')` however 0 rows were effected again. This is bizzare

Comment: Updated please check it once again and thank you for reporting issue

Comment: Error: Token mismatch now :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have an "Id" you could try this way:

```
UPDATE le_wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â', '') 
WHERE Id IN ( SELECT * 
             FROM (
            SELECT Id 
            FROM le_wp_posts 
            WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â%'
                 ) as A
            )
```

Comment: You probably don't need another subselect in the `IN` clause with a `SELECT *`.

Comment: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f5244/1) runs without errors. Different versions or what? I'm curious.

Comment: @KamilG. I use Mysql version 5.6.24 on XAMPP Version: 5.6.8 with PhpMyAdmin  4.5.4.1

Comment: Only MySQL version plays here. Try console to see that it wouldn't yield an error.

Comment: @KamilG. the error only occurs if you reference the same table. Your fiddle references a different table. Also you need to be doing a delete or update to see this.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the expl. It's definitely good to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the update didn't occur from within PhpMyAdmin but from a client?
If so it's just the differing locale settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Query first selects original column as well as replacement string and then update original column
Update Tbl1
Set Tbl1.post_content=Tbl2.Replacement
From le_wp_posts as Tbl1
Inner Join
(
    select post_content,REPLACE(post_content,'Â','') as Replacement
    from le_wp_posts
    where post_content like '%Â%'
) as Tbl2
On Tbl1.post_content=Tbl2.post_content
```